# Combine fill and color legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend, fill

I have found *some* Questions similar to my issue, but none that really fit.
I have 4 data columns I want to plot, 3 as lines and 1 as area.

I'd like to condense the Legend of the resulting Plot into a neat 2 row, 2 column set-up, but I can't seem to figure out how.
Example code:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Random Data
data <- tibble(X=1:50,
               A=sample(seq(5, 6, 0.1), 50, replace = TRUE),
               B=sample(seq(4, 5, 0.1), 50, replace = TRUE),
               C=sample(seq(3, 4, 0.1), 50, replace = TRUE),
               D=sample(seq(1, 3, 0.5), 50, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(data, aes(x=X)) + 
  geom_area(aes(y=D, fill='Dataset4'), alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=A, color='Dataset1')) +
  geom_line(aes(y=B, color='Dataset2')) +
  geom_line(aes(y=C, color='Dataset3')) +
  ylab("")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2, order=2),
         color=guide_legend(nrow=2, order=1))
```

Resulting figure:

[image]

I'd like to have the four legend entries in a 2x2 orientation, is that even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a scale that has colour *and* fill aesthetics. The tricky bit is letting the legend know what should be drawn as a line and what as a polygon, for which I don't have an automatic solution. The manual solution below works, though you'd have to replace the 4th fill with another colour if you use a different scale.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

#Random Data
data <- tibble(X=1:50,
               A=sample(seq(5, 6, 0.1), 50, replace = TRUE),
               B=sample(seq(4, 5, 0.1), 50, replace = TRUE),
               C=sample(seq(3, 4, 0.1), 50, replace = TRUE),
               D=sample(seq(1, 3, 0.5), 50, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(data, aes(x=X)) + 
  geom_area(aes(y=D, fill='Dataset4'), alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=A, color='Dataset1')) +
  geom_line(aes(y=B, color='Dataset2')) +
  geom_line(aes(y=C, color='Dataset3')) +
  scale_colour_discrete(
    name = "",
    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"),
    guide = guide_legend(
      nrow = 2, override.aes = list(
        linetype = c(1, 1, 1, 0),
        fill = c(NA, NA, NA, scales::hue_pal()(4)[4])
      )
    )
  ) +
  ylab("")
#> Warning: Duplicated override.aes is ignored.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>